# sails js authentication middle wares

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am new in node js,  using sails.js as framework for developing application.Have using mysql as database. Need to know, is this possible to add middlewares for admin login check in routes?.

Comment: Policies are intended place for login (authorization) checks. Passport.js can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Sails out of the box [supports all middleware](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware) which are supported by express.

You can very well in use [passport](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/sails-passport) (which though might be an overkill) with sails.